# Root directives inside location being ignored

Tags: web, nginx, server

I have a problem in nginx where the root directive inside location being ignored. Here is the snippet of relevant settings

```
  root /apps/web-ui/latest/;


  location /drop-3 {
    root /apps/web-ui/drop-3/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index2.html;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

When I accessed mysite.com/drop-3/testing, I got 404 and the log showed that nginx tried to access "/apps/web-ui/latest/index2.html"

I have tried using alias and root inside location /drop-3 but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the files for `drop-3` are in `/apps/web-ui/drop-3/drop-3/`, you have the wrong value for your `root` statement.

The path to the file is constructed by concatenating the `root` value with the requested URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The parameters on the `try_files` statement are URIs. The correct URI for `index2.html` within the `drop-3` folder is `/drop-3/index2.html`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location /drop-3 {
    root /apps/web-ui;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /drop-3/index2.html;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and now nginx tried to access /apps/web-ui/latest/drop-3/index2.html which still does not exist. Also I have tried using alias with the same path as root which should omit the location uri but it still tried to access /apps/web-ui/latest

Comment: That's strange, `/drop-3/index2.html` is not matching `location /drop-3`. Double check that the hyphens are the same characters in both expressions. Are there any other `location` blocks that might match the URI?